# Evaluate function inside quotation

Tags: f#

I'm at the moment doing some very basic pattern matching with quotations.

My code:

```
let rec test e =
    match e with
    | Patterns.Lambda(v,e) -> test e
    | Patterns.Call(_, mi, [P.Value(value, _); P.Value(value2, _)]) -> 
        printfn "Value1: %A | Value2 : %A" value value2
    | Patterns.Call(_, mi, [P.Value(value, _); P.PropertyGet(_, pi, exprs)]) ->
        printfn "Value1: %A | Value2 : %A" value (pi.GetValue(pi, null))
    | _ -> failwith "Expression not supported"


let quot1 = <@ "Name" = "MyName" @>
(* Call (None, Boolean op_Equality[String](System.String, System.String),
      [Value ("Name"), Value ("lol")]) *)

let quot2 = <@ "Name" = getNameById 5 @>
(* Call (None, Boolean op_Equality[String](System.String, System.String),
      [Value ("Name"),
       Call (None, System.String getNameById[Int32](Int32), [Value (5)])]) *)

test quot1 // Works!
test quot2 // Fails.. Dosent match any of the patterns.
```

Is it possible to somehow evaluate the result of the `getNameById` function first, so that it will match one of the patterns, or am I doomed to assign a let binding with the result of the function outside the quotation?

I've tried playing with the `ExprShape` patterns, but without luck..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use PowerPack's `Eval` to evaluate only the arguments to the `Call` expression:

```
match e with
| Call(_,mi,[arg1;arg2]) ->
  let arg1Value, arg2Value = arg1.Eval(), arg2.Eval()
  ...
```

And similarly for `Lambda` expressions, etc. Noticed this frees you from enumerating permutations of `Value`, `Property`, and other argument expressions.

**Update**

Since you want to avoid using `Eval` (for good reason if you are implementing a performance conscious application), you'll need to implement your own eval function using reflection (which is still not lightening fast, but should be faster than PowerPack's `Eval` which involves an intermediate translation of F# Quotations to Linq Expressions). You can get started by supporting a basic set of expressions, and expand from there as needed. Recursion is the key, the following can help you get started:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open System.Reflection

let rec eval expr =
    match expr with
    | Patterns.Value(value,_) -> value //value
    | Patterns.PropertyGet(Some(instance), pi, args) -> //instance property get
        pi.GetValue(eval instance, evalAll args) //notice recursive eval of instance expression and arg expressions
    | Patterns.PropertyGet(None, pi, args) -> //static property get
        pi.GetValue(null, evalAll args)
    | Patterns.Call(Some(instance), mi, args) -> //instance call
        mi.Invoke(eval instance, evalAll args)
    | Patterns.Call(None, mi, args) -> //static call
        mi.Invoke(null, evalAll args)
    | _ -> failwith "invalid expression"
and evalAll exprs =
    exprs |> Seq.map eval |> Seq.toArray
```

And then wrapping this in an Active Pattern will improve syntax:

```
let (|Eval|) expr =
    eval expr

match e with 
| Patterns.Call(_, mi, [Eval(arg1Value); Eval(arg2Value)]) -> ...
```

**Update 2**

OK, this thread got me motivated to try and implement a robust reflection based solution, and I've done so with good results which are now part of [Unquote](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/) as of version 2.0.0.

It turned out not to be as difficult as I thought it would be, currently I am supporting all quotation expressions *except* for AddressGet, AddressSet, and NewDelegate. This is already better than PowerPack's eval, which doesn't support PropertySet, VarSet, FieldSet, WhileLoop, ForIntegerRangeLoop, and Quote for example.

Some noteworthy implementation details are with VarSet and VarGet, where I need to pass around an environment name / variable lookup list to each recursive call. It is really an excellent example of the beauty of functional programming with immutable data-structures.

Also noteworthy is special care taken with issues surrounding exceptions: striping the TargetInvokationExceptions thrown by reflection when it catches exceptions coming from methods it is invoking (this is very important for handling TryWith evaluation properly, and also makes for better user handling of exceptions which fly out of the quotation evaluation.

Perhaps the most "difficult" implementation detail, or really the most grueling, was the need to implement all of the core operators (well, as most I could discover: the numeric and conversion operators, checked versions as well) since most of them are not given dynamic implementations in the F# library (they are implemented using static type tests with no fallback dynamic implementations), but also means a serious performance increase when using these functions.

Some informal benchmarking I observe performance increases of up to 50 times over PowerPack's (not pre-compiled) eval.

I am also confident that my reflection-based solution will be less bug prone then PowerPack's, simply because it is less complicated than the PowerPack's approach (not to mention I've backed it up with about 150 unit tests, duly fortified by Unquotes additional 200+ unit tests which now is driven by this eval implementation).

If you want to peek at the source code, the main modules are [Evaluation.fs](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/source/browse/trunk/Unquote/Evaluation.fs?r=257) and [DynamicOperators.fs](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/source/browse/trunk/Unquote/DynamicOperators.fs?r=257) (I've locked the links into revision 257). Feel free to grab and use the source code for your own purposes, it licensed under Apache License 2.0! Or you could wait a week or so, when I release Unquote 2.0.0 which will include evaluation operators and extensions publicly.

Comment: @Stephen, yea that would work.. but I'm still wondering whether it will affect the perfomance of my app since I've heard quite a few bad things about the `.Eval()` function and its perfomance.

Comment: I use `Eval` a lot in Unquote and yes, it's not as fast as it could be but it is certainly sufficient for Unquote's job. But for your project, translating F# expressions into database queries, I would be wary.

Comment: @ebb - I updated my answer with the beginnings of a reflection-based eval function which should perform better than PowerPack's `Eval` and may be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: @Stephen, Thats perfect! :) - But.. how would you go around and implement ex: `Patterns.NewUnionCase`, since it consist of a `UniCaseInfo` and a `Expr list`?

Comment: @ebb, I thought you'd appreciate that! Check out, for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340309.aspx. I think the following would work: `... | Patterns.NewUnionCase(uci, args) -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(uci, evalAll args) ...`. Look around `System.Reflection` and `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` for functions to help you reflectively create different kinds of objects. It will certainly be a lot of work to implement a robust eval engine.

Comment: Nice solution :-). The `Eval` function is not fast, because it translates quotation to C# expression tree and then compiles that. If you need to run the same code multiple times, then you can use `Compile` and then run the compiled function repeatedly - that should be faster than reflection-based solution (if you amortize the cost of the initial compilation).

Comment: @ebb, @Tomas - check out my latest update, I couldn't help myself and implemented a robust reflection-based quotation evaluator which is going to back my upcoming 2.0.0 release of Unquote.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an interpreter that will evaluate the quotation and call the `getNameById` function using Reflection. However, that would be quite a lot of work. The `ExprShape` isn't going to help you much - it is useful for simple traversing of quotations, but to write an interpreter, you'll need to cover all patterns.

I think the easiest option is to evaluate quotations using the PowerPack support:

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll"

open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation

let getNameById n = 
  if n = 5 then "Name" else "Foo"

let quot1 = <@ "Name" = "MyName" @>
let quot2 = <@ "Name" = getNameById 5 @>

quot1.Eval()    
quot2.Eval()
```

This has some limitations, but it is really the easiest option. However, I'm not really sure what are you trying to achieve. If you could clarify that, then you may get a better answer.

Comment: I'm writing a simple quotation translater for mongodb. Ex: You pass in `<@ fun z -> z.Name = getNameById 5 @>` and it will match up against some patterns in order to build a valid mongo query, using its own query functions. The `.Eval()` dosent really help, since it evaluates the whole quotation and not just the `getNameById` function inside.

Comment: @ebb Oh, I see. And how do you want to translate the function call?

Comment: The `getNameById` function? hehe.. yea I've thought about that one for a few days now, and I'm still blank. My only idea was to somehow evaluate the function before passing the quotation to the pattern matching, but that seems impossible..